# Flask AJAX: Bad Request. The CSRF token is missing

Tags: python, ajax, flask, csrf-token

I am facing a problem while sending a request using ajax to flask server. I have attached HTML, js and python file for reference. 
[Html Form Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W2IL.png)

[AJAX request code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLtG9.png)

[python file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUz9w.png)

I have tried various solutions for this problem researching on the internet. I will be grateful if I got out of this problem.

Comment: Please describe the problem you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On your Ajax call, you must add your CSRF Token on request header, not on payload data as you are sending now, e.g:

```
var csrf_token = "{{ csrf_token() }}";

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/login',
    headers: {
        "X-CSRFToken": csrf_token,
    }
    data: {
     ...
```

Hope it suits you well :)

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use the ajaxSetup() method from jQuery. This method will set default values for future AJAX requests. It should look like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
            }
        });

        // Your javascript codes...
    });
</script>
```